# How to insert images in list or select

Tags: html, css

I want to add image to input type=select.

But how to do so I don't know.
I know how to simply add text to it like :

```
<select>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HTML:

```
<select id="listdata">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
select#listdata option[value="1"]   { background-image:url(1.png);   }
select#listdata option[value="2"] { background-image:url(2.png); }
select#listdata option[value="3"] { background-image:url(3.png); }
```

OR

```
<select>
  <option style="background-image:url(1.png);">1</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(2.png);">2</option>
  <option style="background-image:url(3.png);">3</option>
</select>
```

But first one is good to implement.

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ well, already upvoted, but you can take out `select` from your selector and make it a bit short, as Id will be unique, so won't require such level of specific selector, also, you can use quotes around your `url` just for a safe measure :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 <select>
   <option class ="demo" value="a">a</option>
   <option class ="demo" value="b">b</option>
   <option class ="demo" value="c">c</option>
 </select>
```

CSS

```
 .demo
 {
     background-image:url(image.png); 
 }
```

Or

```
 <select id="another_demo">
   <option>a</option>
   <option>b</option>
   <option>c</option>
 </select>
```

Css

```
 select#another_demo option[value="a"]   { background-image:url(a.png);   }
 select#another_demo option[value="b"] { background-image:url(b.png); }
 select#another_demo option[value="c"] { background-image:url(c.png); }
```

Comment: inline styles, vintage times

Comment: @Mr.Alien just an example... to make the OP understand the concept.

Comment: Yea, I got that, but what you will write here, say some beginner ended up, and he won't use his brain much, will keep on using this the same way you do it, so better you post, better people will learn :) I specifically posted, because, users may use different classes for each option tag, some may use `nth` or like Java Curious used `element[attr=val]` selector, so you might consider editing your answer and I will upvote ")

Comment: This `demo` will apply the same `background` to all `option` and anyways +1

Answer (score 1):

```
<select>
  <option style="background:url(option1.png);background-size:w h">option1</option>
  <option style="background:url(option2.png);background-size:w h">option2</option>
  <option style="background:url(option3.png);background-size:w h">option3</option>
</select>
```